# After enabling separate process folders, explorer doesn't terminate?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-explorer

I have enabled the option called

> *Launch folders in a separate process*

in *folder Options* but the second explorer.exe process does not terminate after all its  windows are closed , so i have to manually terminate it before any other folder can be opened .

Any idea on how to solve this ?

I am using Windows Vista Home premium Sp2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a rogue Explorer extension installed causing Explorer to hang. [Sysinternals' Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) tool can show you any Explorer extensions; try disabling them and rebooting to see if the problem goes away.